# Cannot seem to style my component via boolean value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Using Styled-components, I am attempting to style custom components based on their content. However I cannot seem to get this quite right.

[Here is a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-1to8x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I believe the issue is with how the `forEach` is bringing the Booleans back, not exiting out at the correct time? I have debugged with console logs, and I can confirm that the function does see when the comparison is correct, it's just that the css is not changed at that point?

**Title.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const toMatch = ["1", "2"];

function doesMatch(name) {
  toMatch.forEach(match => {
    return name.includes(match);
  });
}

export default styled.h1`
  background: ${props => (doesMatch(props.data) ? "blue" : "green")};
`;
```

**Template**

```
const x = [{ name: "1" }, { name: "2" }, { name: "3" }];

const App = () => (
  <Wrapper>
    {x.map(inf => (
      <Title key={inf.name} data={inf.name}>
        {inf.name}
      </Title>
    ))}
  </Wrapper>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Please post the template where you actually use the styled H1.

Comment: @IngoSteinke - Apologies. The `JS` file was actually called `Title.js` with this being used as `<Title>` in the main template.

Comment: That `doesMatch` function doesn't return anything, so obviously it won't work.

Comment: What about the `return name.includes(match);`? Does that not do what I am expecting it to?

Comment: No, it returns only in the body of each callback passed to `forEach`, but not in the `doesMatch` .

Comment: Ah! Thought I was missing something with that! I will revise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `return` value to `doesMatch`, in your case:

```
function doesMatch(name) {
//  v Return a boolean from `doesMatch` function
  return toMatch.find(match => {
//                ^ Change from `forEach` which is void function.
    return name.includes(match);
  });
}
```

- [`#Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`#Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

[image: Edit Styled Components]

Comment: Oh! I'd have never have thought of putting a return on the `.find`!